# Как с помощью регулярных выражений вытащить адреса my ether wallet?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Как с помощью регулярных выражений вытащить адреса my ether wallet? Вот пример таких адресов:

```
0xdad75804e6675c1dfb5c5948cd474595fdd14fdf
0x661b73fdf4aada75e56095b5e93e378cd9fa7401
0x3d3a0380a34d07477cd8a503e6d701d29fc59a19
0x57d21276452202a8229dd2af1f96b88dcabef314
0xb7bd367E8Ba28FbCe0A7BE664ACC4f7510acE2EC
```

Comment: `0x[0-9a-f]{40}`

Comment: `0x[0-9a-fA-F]{40}`

Comment: Блин, конечно, забыл `/i`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# File : get_eth.py   
import re

patern_re = re.compile("0x[0-9a-fA-F]{40}")

string ='''0xdad75804e6675c1dfb5c5948cd474595fdd14fdf
0x661b73fdf4aada75e56095b5e93e378cd9fa7401
0x3d3a0380a34d07477cd8a503e6d701d29fc59a19
0x57d21276452202a8229dd2af1f96b88dcabef314
0xb7bd367E8Ba28FbCe0A7BE664ACC4f7510acE2EC
test-string
'''

print(patern_re.findall(string))
# end of get_eth.py
```

Comment: А почему `{4}`? опечатка?

Comment: @Akina она самая. спасибо.